# how to get number of checked checkboxes in a form?

Tags: list-form

I have a form with several groups of checkboxes.  Is there a way to write a formula to find out how many of them are selected?
To answer ali SharePoint question: I have a custom list, the form is the New Item or Edit item  form. What i'm trying to do is to have a calculated column that will produce  a value, based on the values in the multiple columns. I hope to do it with a nested "If" formula, and I want to figure out how to capture a count of checkboxes selected in some columns as it will impact the result in the calculated column.

Comment: can you be a little bit more specific? like is this on a webpart? where do you want this to occure and where is the form?

Comment: Hi ali SharePoint-

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do so using just a calculated column since multi-value choice columns cannot be used within a formula in SharePoint.  You can do so using client-side JavaScript or CSS, but this will require that you use a tool such as SharePoint Designer to customize the NewForm.aspx file itself.